# What is the direction of normal?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What will be the direction of normal and friction in a case where a spherical body is just about to fall off a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  If both surfaces are "smooth" then there is a local tangent plane for each that coincide at the contact point.  Thus friction would be in the local tangent plane and "normal" in the direction of the local gradient for each surface.  What would it be for a sharp edge in contact?

Comment: Yes i wanted to know about sharp edge

Comment: Can u elaborate about local gradient

Comment: Consider the surface as a function (many common ones can be written as scalar functions) then the gradient of that function is normal to the surface.  If the surface is parameterized by r(u, v) where r is a vector then the local tangents are dr/dv, and dr/du (d = partial).  Then normal is given by the cross product (these are identical descriptions).

Comment: Sharp edges are an issue because the derivative is not defined there (like cusps for a function).  However, (1) if one surface is smooth then you can use that normal to define the contact force.  You could also assume a very small radius of curvature for the sharp edge and perform the analysis that way.  This is probably more realistic and doesn't suffer any pathological behavior.

Comment: You seem to have chosen an answer.  That one mentions one of my described methods of handling the sphere at the edge of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your question i am assuming that the ball is at the table Corner. Then draw a tangent plane at this point to the sphere . The perpendicular to this will give the direction of normal from the point of contact.  Now as the ball is falling  freely under the action of gravity then the component of weight along the tangent pulls it down. Now the ball will be accelerating under the action of weight so while rotating it will be pushing the ground(table corner) in the backward i.e opposite to the weight component and so friction will go in forward direction .
[[Hope the figure makes it clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyzkJ.jpg)]

Comment: I'd like to add: drawing this tangent plane is easy because the corner is a straight line. In a 2D diagram of the tabe, it's one point. The corner is one point, the center of the sphere is another point. The line that connects both points is a radius, and the tangent plane is perpendicualr to that radius, at the contact point.

Comment: You can post pictures within the answer as well.

Comment: What should be the direction of normal when a rod initially kept upright is falling at an arbitrary angle?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The ball roles on the table ,when the ball’s position $x(t)$ is greater than a , then the ball start to fall off the table. For this event we can calculate the tangent vector $t'$ and the normal vector $n'$ .